# SLAM Toolbox : "Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA" when running rosbag in ROS Noetic. How do I get rid of this warning?

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My goal is to use the SLAM toolbox on ROS Noetic with a rosbag (recorded on ROS Melodic).
When I launch the SLAM toolbox in one terminal and play the rosbag in another terminal and open RVIZ in a third terminal. I get the following warning message on the terminal that launches the slam toolbox:

**Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame odom at time 1609136889.260522 according to authority unknown_publisher
at line 278 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-noetic-tf2-0.7.5/src/buffer_core.cpp**

I also get the following warning on the terminal that launches RVIZ :

**[ WARN] [1609407684.995474563, 1609136889.060521646]: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame odom at time 1609136889.260522 according to authority unknown_publisher**

My rosbag has the following topics published :

1. /scan
2. /odom
3. /tf

Why do i get this warning and how can I get rid of it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368709/slam-toolbox-:-%22warning:-tf_repeated_data%22-when-running-rosbag-in-ros-noetic.-how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-warning-?/) by [ankurb](https://answers.ros.org/users/66796/ankurb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-12-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-26**:
See #q381529 on how to suppress the warning

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I now get the same with Cartographer ...

There is comment @ https://answers.ros.org/question/359968/tf_repeated_data-error-with-robot_localization-ukf-package/

and @ https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/467

Not sure these fix it tho ?

again any ideas ?

---

Originally posted by [Slider](https://answers.ros.org/users/61390/slider/) with karma: 51 on 2021-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same problem, any fix for this?

---

Originally posted by [owner](https://answers.ros.org/users/69328/owner/) with karma: 11 on 2021-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1